# Execute function if there are more than 2 lines in a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I execute  a function if the text in a div causes there to be more than 1 line? (e.g, the words wrap to form 2 or more lines)

I wish that if it does exceed 1 line, I execute a function (in this case, adding a 'Show more' button).

Currently, I've tried checking the length, but this does not work because the length is not always an indicator of a newline because it changes on different screens.

Before is my attempt:

```js
$(function(){
  let len = 80;
  $('.demo').each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().length >len){   
        var str=$(this).html().substring(0,len-1)+"..."+
        "<a href='https://www.hinet.net/' target='_blank'>show more</a>";
        $(this).html(str);
      } 
  });
});
```

```css
.demo{
    max-width: 600px;
    border:1px solid #222;  
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipi</p>
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest approach is probably to the apply the CSS rule `white-space:nowrap` to force it onto a single line, check the height using `.offsetHeight` and compare it with the original height.

If it is smaller, it's an indicator that there is more than 1 line (if it was already 1 line, forcing it to one line wouldn't change the `offsetHeight`).

The example below illustrates how it works:

```js
var text = $('div');
var prev = text[0].offsetHeight;
text.css({'white-space': 'nowrap', 'overflow':'hidden'});
var now = text[0].offsetHeight;
text.css('white-space','initial');
if(now < prev){
  console.log("more than 1 line");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The text in this div should exceed two lines. The text in this div should exceed two lines. The text in this div should exceed two lines. The text in this div should exceed two lines.</div>
```

When there is only 1 line:

```js
var text = $('div');
var prev = text[0].offsetHeight;
text.css({'white-space': 'nowrap', 'overflow':'hidden'});
var now = text[0].offsetHeight;
text.css('white-space','initial');
if(now < prev){
  console.log("more than 1 line");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The text in this div is only 1 line.</div>
```

Here's it fine tuned to your case:

```js
var text = $('div');
var prev = text[0].offsetHeight;
text.css({'white-space': 'nowrap', 'overflow':'hidden'});
var now = text[0].offsetHeight;
if(now < prev){
  text.append('<br/><a href="#">Show more...</a>');
  $('a').on('click', ()=>{
    text.css('white-space','initial');
  })
}else{
  text.css('white-space','initial');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The text in this div should exceed 2 lines. The text in this div should exceed 2 lines. The text in this div should exceed 2 lines. The text in this div should exceed 2 lines. </div>
```